# Managing Shared Models in Micro-Frontend Architecture

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, single-spa-angular

I am currently working on an Angular project with many modules out of which 'admin' and 'account' Both modules share common models stored in a shared folder. Looking ahead, we are considering transitioning to a micro-frontend architecture. I'm seeking guidance on the best approach for managing shared models in a micro-frontend environment. Here are some considerations:

1. Shared Module Approach:
   Will increase the size of shared module which can be hosted as separate micro frontend but size will grow and will always be loaded even if application module requires part of it.
2. Individual Module Approach:
   Will result into duplication of models and if any change in models then needs to replicated into multiple micro frontend.
3. Package as External Libraries:
   Not sure about this, but we can keep all shared models as part of library and use that library wherever required.

I personally think option 3 as good approach but need suggestions from experts who has already faced this issue.

Comment: _"Micro-Frontend Architecture"_ - Are you sure this is appropriate for your application?

Comment: Option 3 still has the "but size will grow and will always be loaded" problem of Option 1.

Comment: _"Individual Module Approach: Will result into duplication of models and if any change in models then needs to replicated into multiple micro frontend."_ - Why would any duplication happen here?

Comment: Anyway, if those "models" are actual DTOs then they represent your **data contract**, which means you _should only ever have a single, canonical definition of them_, otherwise they'll go-out-of-sync and things will break. Don't forget that multiple projects can still share source-files with other projects (e.g. symlinks, git subtrees / submodules, etc) without needing any duplication - or unnecessary loading/use of unused types.

Comment: @Dai but we will not load the entire MF but only models(no comps, no services etc). In option 1 we were thinking about having shared MF which will always load in browser.

Comment: @Dai We are initially starting with submodules for the shared services and presentation stuff, but eventually wants to get rid of the that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to build a components library in the same way that projects such as Angular Material do.

Making it a shared module will work if your overarching project is basically everything in a monorepo, so you can keep all of the code up to date. This approach would also work for a smaller team that modify all of the code.

If your team is larger or you want even greater re-use of your components across many applications, an external library approach works better. That creates some distance between the components and the projects so things will need to have clearer API contracts and things may go out of date easier.

Comment: Concern is, as we are following clean architecture and DDD, we need to keep models where these are being responsible. identifying logical domain boundary and then using those models at runtime. If we define models in account MF, when browser will load admin MF we will not have access to account MF modules